Trademarked Name Use in Novel
Can I have a character's name be the same as the one in a popular children's book?
For example, the kids in a neighborhood think an old man is hiding something.  This has been going on for years and generations and is like an urban legend.  They think he might be Batman.  The old man's name also happens to be Bruce Wayne.  He's not really batman.
The name Batman isn't in my book, but is a good example to represent my question.  The "Bruce Wayne" in my book is not a main character, but his role in the book is significant.

Hey Kristy, the way this site works it is expected that you only ask one question per question. I have therefore deleted one and answered the other. — Your question about citing from existing works has very likely already been answered on this site. There is a site search at the top of each page. There is a difference between citing from poetry or songs and citing from longer works, as well as between citing from current works and older works whose copyright has expired, so make sure you search for the right thing (or ask your new question with enough details).

Briefly: You must gain permission to cite even one line from a song or poem but you can cite a sentence or two from a novel. And you don't need any permission if the copyright has expired (usually 70 years after the death of the author) or the work is in the public domain. If your case is more complicated than that, please ask a new question.

There is no problem at all if your narrator or characters use a trademarked name like Batman in your novel. For example, there is no infringement if one character says something like, "Who do you think I am? Batman?"
In your example case, though, the whole story is built around the idea that the kids believe one other character is Batman. Batman (the name, his appearance, and other aspects of that franchise) will therefore feature prominently, centrally, and continually throughout the story, and the story wouldn't work without that reference to Batman and completely evaporate without him.
In that case, there is a clear infringement because that story's success is built upon the popularity and success of Batman.
What authors usually do in such a case is invent their own superhero. Your story doesn't need Batman. It works just as well with any other superhero. Your readers will connect the non-existing superhero in your story with the ones they know from other media and understand what you mean. It's a bit like situating a story in a made up town in California or featuring a made up president of the USA.
